# Batch Files - Closing Opened Text Files

Tags: batch-file, text-files

I currently have a Windows batch file that runs an .exe file that uses a text file. I am trying to have the Windows batch file run the .exe file multiple times. This, however, requires the use of the same text files to read from. The command prompt gives me the error that the ".txt could not be opened" (I assume from this that it is already open.)

I am trying to see if there is a way in a .bat file to system call to kill that specific text file. The suggestions I see online are to use 'taskkill notepad.exe', but that returns "invalid argument" because the program doesn't open Notepad to use the text file.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: So - what application do **you** use to "run" a textfile?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your existing script fails because the first instance of the exe is still open when the second instance starts.

One thing worth trying (and this depends on the nature of the application you are invoking) is to start the executable using the `START /WAIT /B ...` command. This makes the command interpreter wait for the program to exit before it moves onto the next command, so as long as nothing else is locking the text files you should be OK to move onto the next command.

Comment: Okay, this was somewhat helpful. I find that now the .exe completes in a split-second, which means it doesn't actually run. If I simply use the command "run.exe" in the cmd, it will take approx. 5 mins to run. The line I currently use to run goes as follows 'FOR /L %%c IN (1,1,%reps%) DO (START "%homedir%\output\%%c\run.exe" /WAIT /B ...)'. I will also note that your solution makes a file folder open of the home directory, which was... unexpected. (I appreciate the help.)

Comment: START is fiddly. That first argument has quotes around it, which provokes the behaviour you have observed (look at the help for START...). Try adding an empty string as the first command - `START "" "%homedir....`